# How to apply different frames on image border in flutter

Tags: flutter, border, frame

I search a lot how to apply frame on images but found no answer. I read stack function in which we can put an image inside other but its not good trick. I think there must be library for frame and by using that frame can automatically apply on border of image. Please guide me how can I use different design of frame outside image like some filters application.
[image]

I want to give options of frame to user like below and when user click on any frame that will apply on image

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches for that issue. I've used several in the past. It strongly differs in the way you want to make use of the image. Do you need to paint something on the image or just display it?

In my opinion multiple frames on an image can be achieved best with `CustomPainter`. Check out the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html) for more. The following Painter should do the trick.

```
class TestPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final ui.Image image;

  TestPainter({required this.image});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    //draw the image
    canvas.drawImage(image, const Offset(0, 0), Paint());

    double rectWidth = image.width.toDouble();
    double rectHeight = image.height.toDouble();
    final imageCenter = Offset(image.width / 2, image.height / 2);

    //first frame
    var border1 = Rect.fromCenter(
     center: imageCenter,
     width: rectWidth + 1,
     height: rectHeight + 1);

    var painting = Paint();
    painting.color = Colors.red;
    painting.strokeWidth = 2;
    painting.style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    canvas.drawRect(border1, painting);

    //second frame
    var border2 = Rect.fromCenter(
     center: imageCenter,
     width: rectWidth + 3,
     height: rectHeight + 3);

    var painting2 = Paint();
    painting2.color = Colors.green;
    painting2.strokeWidth = 2;
    painting2.style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    canvas.drawRect(
     border2,
     painting2,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Please be cautious. The Image in that example needs to be an Image of the `dart:ui` library ([Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/dart-ui-library.html)). There are various way to convert. Depends on your project.

Comment: Thanks for reply sir, I edit question. I want to give different option like given picture and when user click some frame it will apply on border of image

Comment: please tell me how to pass image to ui.image as I take image from gallery so how can I call testpainter by passing gallery image which is a file

Answer (score 0):

You can load `ui.Image` from `Image.asset` with the following

```
Future<ui.Image> load(String asset) async {
  ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(asset);
  ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(data.buffer.asUint8List());
  ui.FrameInfo fi = await codec.getNextFrame();
  return fi.image;
}
```